# abort() triggers Error Undefined in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, abort

I use the following code to throttle get requests in race conditions:

```
        if (currentAjaxRequest !== null) {
            currentAjaxRequest.abort();
        }   
        var query_string = getQuery();
        currentAjaxRequest = $.get(query_string, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            if (xhr.status) {  
                currentAjaxRequest = null;
                // do stuff
            }                       
        });
```

I've noticed that in Chrome that when the abort is called an error pops up in the javascript console:

GET undefined (undefined)

This does not seem to impact the script at all - everything continues to run just fine.  Is there anything I should be doing to correct this?  Or is this just the way chrome reports an aborted ajax request?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I've noticed this same thing (except with POST)... not sure why it shows an error for abort.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably right in thinking it's the way Chrome reports an aborted request. jQuery calls the XMLHttpRequest's abort() method. The recommendation of how this method should be implemented from the W3C can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-abort-method).

Step 6 of this process is "set the error flag to true", so although Chrome thinks there's an error to report it's undefined as the error message hasn't been set inside the request object.